# What is the earliest timestamp value that is supported in ZIP file format?

Tags: zip, specifications, file-format

I am trying to store dates as latest modification timestamp in a ZIP -file. It seems that ZIP format support only dates after 1980-01-01 as a last modification time (at least via Java API [java.util.zip.ZipEntry](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) )

Is this correct? Is the earliest supported modification timestamp really 1980-01-01 00:00:00? I tried to find some references to verify this but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Zip entry timestamps are recorded only
>   to two 2 second precision. This
>   reflects the accuracy of DOS
>   timestamps in use when PKZIP was
>   created. That number recorded in the
>   Zip will be the timestamp truncated,
>   not the nearest 2 seconds.
>
> When you archive and restore a file,
>   it will no longer have a timestamp
>   precisely matching the original. This
>   is above and beyond he similar problem
>   with Java using 1 millisecond
>   precision and Microsoft Windows using
>   100 nanosecond increments. PKZIP
>   format derives from MS DOS days and
>   hence uses only 16 bits for time and
>   16 bits for date. There is defined an
>   extended time stamp in the revised
>   PKZIP format, but Java does not use
>   it.
>
> Inside zip files, dates and times are
>   stored in local time in 16 bits, not
>   UTC as is conventional, using an
>   ancient MS DOS format. Bit 0 is the
>   least signifiant bit. The format is
>   little-endian. There was not room in
>   16 bit to accurately represent time
>   even to the second, so the seconds
>   field contains the seconds divided by
>   two, giving accuracy only to the even
>   second.
>
> This means the apparent time of files
>   inside a zip will suddenly differ by
>   an hour compared with their
>   uncompressed counterparts every time
>   you have a daylight saving change. It
>   also means that the a zip utility will
>   extract a different UTC time from a
>   Zip member date depending on which
>   timezone the calculation was done.
>   This is ridiculous. PKZIP format needs
>   a modern UTC-based timestamp to avoid
>   these anomalies.
>
> To make matters worse, Standard tools
>   like WinZip or PKZIP will always round
>   the time up to the next even second
>   when they restore, thereby possibly
>   making the file one second to two
>   seconds younger. The JDK (i.e.
>   javaToDosTime in ZipEntry rounds the
>   time down, thereby making the file one
>   to two seconds older.
>
> The format does not support dates
>   prior to 1980-01-01 0:00 UTC. Avoid
>   file dates 1980-01-01 or earlier
>   (local or UTC time).
>
> Wait! It gets even worse. Phil Katz,
>   when he documented the Zip format, did
>   not bother to specify whether the
>   local time used in the archive should
>   be daylight or standard time.
>
> And to cap it off… Info-ZIP, JSE and
>   TrueZIP apply the DST schedule (days
>   where DST began and ended in any given
>   year) for any date when converting
>   times between system time and DOS
>   date/time. This is as it should be.
>   Vista’s Explorer, 7-Zip and WinZip
>   apply only the DST savings, but do not
>   apply the schedule. So they use the
>   current DST savings for any date when
>   converting times between system time
>   and DOS date/time. This is just
>   sloppy.

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/zip.html

`tar` files are *so* much better.